# Recording the sale of a partially depreciated asset?

Tags: depreciation

I have some equipment that my small business was in the process of depreciating. It was originally purchased in 2016 (totally roughly $4,500) and was partially depreciated at the end of 2016 (roughly $1,500 of it).

In 2017, I sold this equipment for $3,000. When I asked my accountant how to record this, he said record a credit to the equipment account and a debit to the depreciation account.

My question is, this is 3 transactions? 1) the income to my bank account, 2) the credit to the equipment account, 3) the debit to fixed assets?

How do I make this balance? I can record #1 as a credit to the equipment account, but when I try to do a journal entry for #3 it won't let me unless the credits and debits balance, so I end up with double the credits to the equipment account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more an accounting question, and your accountant should be able to clarify, but typically:

1. Debit `Cash` for the sale amount
2. Debit `Accumulated Depreciation` to remove the asset's accumulated depreciation
3. Credit the `Equipment` account to remove the equipment cost
4. Balance the journal entry with a debit/credit to record profit or loss (if a credit is needed to balance, then you have a gain on sale).

Comment: Thanks. I think where I am getting messed up is the actual income is coming in from Cash and I have to put that credit somewhere. So I am putting it on the equipment account. But when i try to do the journal entry to record the debit it makes me record a SECOND credit to the equipment account. So I'm recording the credit twice.

Comment: I assume "it" is your accounting software and not your accountant, what are you using?

Comment: Correct. I use Zoho Books. I think I figured it out. I was thinking I should somehow only have two transactions and that the income transaction also had to be the credit to the equipment account. But I think I understand that the journal entry for the debit/credits is a separate things. So I did one transaction to record the income then a separate journal entry for the equipment and depreciation accounts.